# Rooting Huawei mediapad T3 7 Wifi

Tags: rooting

I want to flash magisk on my device but i haven't been able to unlock the bootloader. I was wondering if i could patch the boot.img of the firmware file i found online then flash it with spflash tool. Would it work? Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Since mid 2018 Huawei does no longer allow to unlock devices, hence rooting Huawei devices has become extremely difficult. https://www.xda-developers.com/xda-huawei-decision-stop-bootloader-unlocking/

Comment: if SP Flash Tool can by-pass secure boot and flash it that will work. in Magisk Manager Advanced Settings enable keep avb/dm-verity preserve force encryption. but do a readback first for backup purposes

Comment: another method try mtk-su not sure it works for MT8127

Comment: or buy unlock code from dc unlocker